# Java no Eclipse: exibindo muitos warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

Estou começando a estudar Java utilizando a IDE Eclipse, que tem me ajudado bastante neste início na criação de classes e telas.

Gostaria de saber se é normal ele ficar exibindo muitos warnings? Eu tenho que verificar todos eles? É normal o Eclipse agir assim ou eu estou fazendo algo errado?

As aplicações não estão dando erros e estão funcionando normalmente. Porém essa chuva de warnings está me preocupando se estou começando errado.

Qual a opinião/sugestão de quem está usando o Eclipse com Java sobre esses warnings?

Seguem alguns que apareceram:

```java
    JList list = new JList();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
    DefaultListModel lstModelo = new DefaultListModel();
```

> JList is a raw type. References to generic type JList should be parameterized
>
> DefaultListModel is a raw type. References to generic type DefaultListModel should be parameterized

Comment: Mostra uns warnings ai

Comment: Math, incluí alguns na pergunta.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que você precisa colocar o tipo do atributo na lista, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa Tarde, tudo bem?

Sim, é normal que o eclipse exiba os warinigs para você.

Em teoria, para o compilador, não tem nada de errado no seu projeto. Quem exibe esses warnings é a própria IDE.

O que você precisa verificar é:

Atributos criados que não são utilizados, seja dentro de um método ou utilizando getter e setter.

Se você criou métodos que não são utilizados.

Utilização de métodos que estão depreciados.

Importações que não são utilizadas, isso é comum no estudo, exemplo, você cria um ArrayList para algum teste, logo em seguida exclui esse ArrayList, o import dele ficará na classe, isso gera warning tambem.

O ideal é que você clique no warning, leia-o e resolva possivel.

Abraço

Comment: Caio, legal a sua explicação. Eu incluí alguns na pergunta. Quando são avisos de propriedades não utilizadas ou não inicializadas, tudo bem. Porém às vezes aparecem outros que eu ainda não consigo entender para resolver, ou se nem preciso me importar com eles.